# Design & Assign Firestore RBAC to specific collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, rbac

I'm designing a RBAC for my large system using firestore database. So I want to assign each access rights to each User to each Collection.

So what I'm going to ask is my current design.

This is just an example of bunch of collection in my database.

[You can see the image design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swpUg.png)

So my idea is to put a Map contains below data:

**Permission**

- read: array of user_ids
- write: array of user_ids
- update: array of user_ids
- delete: array of user_ids

Is it possible to create the security rules based on my current design to achieve the flexibility of RBAC? Any advice about the example security rules for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get familiar with [Security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure). This concept is a simple syntax solution to  provide access control.

There is a nice [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access#solution_role-based_access_control) in Google documentation that shows how to implement RBAC in Firestore with security rules. Looking at your question I think that it's describing exactly your problem.